# How to replace next word after a match in perl or sed expression?

Tags: perl, sed

I'm trying to replace doxygen comment from a file with swift comments.

e.g: `/// \param foo` should became `/// - Parameter foo:` with foo

So far I have

`gsed -i 's/\\param/\- Parameter/g' my_file` or `perl -pe 's/\\param/\- Parameter/g'`

I'd like to replace the following `word` (foo) after my expression with `word:` (foo:)

I didn't manage to find a good expression for that. Ideally, something that work on Linux and macOS

Answer (score 3):

In perl you can capture and put back the word with `$1` (first parentheses).

```
s/\\param\s+(.+)/- Parameter $1:/g
```

`.+` will capture the rest of that line. If that is something you don't want, and just want to capture the first word, you can use `\S+` or `\w+` or whatever other character class that matches the characters you want to capture, e.g. `[a-z_-]+`.

In sed it is probably `\1`.

Comment: Not good because it will place : at the end of the line not at the end of foo

It became:

`/// - Parameter account Account to get the extended public key of.:`

Comment: I used `.+` on purpose to include everything on the line, since you did not specify what could be on the line. If you want just one word, you can use `\w+` instead, but then you cannot get `\\param foo bar - Foobar stuff`.

Comment: No need for `\ ` in `\-`

Comment: Right, I didn't even see that, just copy pasted the OP's substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\\(param)( [^ ]*)/- \u\1eter\2:/' input_file
/// - Parameter foo:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pattern with a single capture group, and use that group with `\1` in the replacement.

```
sed -E 's/\\param[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+)/- Parameter \1:/g' my_file
```

The pattern matches:

- `\\param` Match `\param`
- `[[:space:]]+` Match 1+ spaces
- `([^[:space:]]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars

Output

```
- Parameter foo:
```

If you validated the output, then you can change `sed -E`  to `sed -Ei` to do the replacement.